# How to animate an SVG element along a path from its last/current position (SMIL only, no CSS & no js)?

Tags: svg, path, smil

I'm looking to animate a svg element along a path WITHOUT CSS  or Javascript, just with the SMIL. What I'm looking to do is:

1. Play an animation on an element
2. Get this element to stay in the final position when the animation end
3. Start the next animation applied to this element FROM its current position

I've been figuring out so far how to get to the point 2 by using & setting the attribute `fill="freeze"` but I can't get to find a way to make it to my point 3... Each time, the element restart from its initial position.

Here, a snippet to watch the desired effect (done with js there).
I was wondering if it was actually possible just with SMIL ?
And if so, what should I  explore to make it ?

```js
let animation = document.querySelector('#behavior_desired');

animation.addEventListener('endEvent', () => {
  let circle=document.querySelector('#element_animated');
  let newCX = circle.cx.animVal.value + 180;
  let newCY = circle.cy.animVal.value + 35; 
  circle.setAttribute("cx", newCX);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", newCY);
  animation.setAttribute("fill", "remove");
})

animation.addEventListener('beginEvent', () => {
  animation.setAttribute("fill", "freeze");
})
```

```html
<h2>Element final position (after animation): INITIAL</h2>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="auto" height="auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 200" style="background-color: #0010ff3b;">
  <path fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke="black" id="draw" d="m 100, 100 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
  <circle r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" cx="100" cy="100">
    <animateMotion dur="1s" fill="" begin="click">
      <mpath xlink:href="#motionpath"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" id="motionpath" stroke="none" d="m 0, 0 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
</svg>

<h2>Element final position (after animation): LAST FRAME</h2>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="auto" height="auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 200" style="background-color: #0010ff3b;">
  <path fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke="black" id="draw2" d="m 100, 100 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
  <circle r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" cx="100" cy="100">
    <animateMotion dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="click">
      <mpath xlink:href="#motionpath2"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" id="motionpath2" stroke="none" d="m 0, 0 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
</svg>

<h2>Desired behavior:</h2>
<p>After being animated, if we click on the element to re-launch the animation on it, I want that the animation starts with the element  at its current position</p>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="auto" height="auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-30 -30 800 400" style="background-color: #0010ff3b;">
  <path fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke="black" id="draw3" d="m 0, 100 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="5,5" id="draw4" d="m 180, 135 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="2,2" id="draw5" d="m 360, 170 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="1,1" id="draw5" d="m 540, 205 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
  <circle id="element_animated" r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" cx="0" cy="100">
    <animateMotion id="behavior_desired" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="click">
      <mpath xlink:href="#motionpath3"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <path fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" id="motionpath3" stroke="none" d="m 0, 0 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Just with SMIL, no.

Comment: @RobertLongson I suspected it but we never know, might miss a trick :D 
Thanx for the light !

Comment: Best you could do is have lots of objects with all but the first being display:none then each time an animation ends you make the next one display: block and animate that. Lot of duplication though and only works for a fixed number of steps.

Comment: Could you use a relative path? (i.e. small letters "l", "m" etc.) and then have the animation start on each click of it? and set each fill="freeze"? Conceptually in my brain it makes sense but I need to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought that this would have worked (see: https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#Accumulate):

```
  <path transform="translate(100, 100)" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" id="motionpath" stroke="black" d="m 0, 0 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
  <circle id="circle" r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" cx="100" cy="100">
    <animateMotion begin="click" dur="1s" fill="freeze" addative="replace" accumulate="sum">
      <mpath xlink:href="#motionpath"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
```

But it clearly does not.

I tried a bunch of ways including looking into this sort of idea:

```
  <circle id="circle" r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" cx="100" cy="100">    
    <animate attributeName="cx" from="100" by="+180" begin="circle.click" dur="1s" fill="freeze"  additive="replace" accumulate="sum"></animate>
    <animate attributeName="cy" from="100" by="+35" begin="circle.click" dur="1s" fill="freeze"  additive="replace" accumulate="sum"></animate>
  </circle>
```

(was focussed on the behaviour [before considering the path] as I thought this would add 180 to the cx and add 35 to the cy each click but it did not).

None of my attempts worked.

The only way I found was with JS (using accumulate from the first example), however, I think my JS way is more robust and re-usable than that in the question, so maybe it helps a little?

(You can set the repeatCount in the `<animateMotion>` tag and this will be considered in the JS, and each iteration it doesn't jump around like the demo in the question etc.)

Demo on CodePen (or below): https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/VwLmKVd

[image]

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const circle = document.querySelector('#circle');
const motionP = document.querySelector('#motionpath');
let animateM = document.querySelector('#circle > animateMotion');

let currentRepeatCount = 0;
const RepeatCount = animateM.getAttribute('repeatCount');
animateM.setAttribute('repeatCount', 'indefinite');

animateM.addEventListener('repeatEvent', (e) => {
  currentRepeatCount +=1;
  console.log(currentRepeatCount);
  svg.pauseAnimations();
});

circle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  animateM = document.querySelector('#circle > animateMotion');
  if (currentRepeatCount == 0){
    animateM.beginElement();
  } else if (currentRepeatCount == RepeatCount){
    return void(0);
  } else {    
    svg.unpauseAnimations();
  }  
})
```

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="auto" height="auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 900 400" style="background-color: #0010ff3b;">
  <path transform="translate(100, 100)" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="bevel" id="motionpath" stroke="black" d="m 0, 0 c 40,0 45,35 180,35"></path>
  <circle id="circle" r="25" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" cx="100" cy="100">
    <animateMotion begin="indefinite" dur="1s" fill="freeze" addative="replace" accumulate="sum" repeatCount="4">
      <mpath xlink:href="#motionpath"></mpath>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>  
</svg>
```

If you want to move the path along with us we can edit the repeat event:

```
animateM.addEventListener('repeatEvent', (e) => {
  currentRepeatCount +=1;
  console.log(currentRepeatCount);
  svg.pauseAnimations();
  if (currentRepeatCount < RepeatCount){
    const box = circle.getBoundingClientRect();
    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = (box.left + box.right) / 2;
    pt.y = (box.top + box.bottom) / 2;
    var svgP = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    console.log(svgP.x,svgP.y)
    motionP.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${svgP.x}, ${svgP.y})`)
  }
});
```

And we get this nice behaviour:

[image]

Comment: So no "ONLY SMIL" :))  for the javascript part, the pause/unpause is smart but it might block all the eventual others animations of the svg (which is my case, I simplified it here just for the example)